# Как сделать диалоговое окно на Javascript, типа alert()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно сделать диалоговое окно на Javascript, типа alert(). Только, чтобы было две кнопки "Да" и "Нет", при нажатии "Да" срабатывает один код, при нажатии "Нет" другой. Как реализовать на JS?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: `confirm`, но лучше не использовать системные модальные окна, а реализовывать их как один из элементов, которые показываются или скрываются

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334636/how-to-create-a-dialog-with-yes-and-no-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (confirm("Сказать привет?")) {
  alert("Привет!")
} else {
  alert("Вы нажали кнопку отмена")
}
```

Ну или кастомные

http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/